# Installation error: Please change the value of 'Security.salt' in app/config/core.php to a salt value specific to your application

Tags: php, cakephp

When trying to install CakePHP, I get the following error message about changing the values of the salt and cipher seed. How can I change these values?

```
Notice (1024): Please change the value of 'Security.salt' in app/config/core.php to a salt value specific to your application [CORE\cake\libs\debugger.php, line 684]
Notice (1024): Please change the value of 'Security.cipherSeed' in app/config/core.php to a numeric (digits only) seed value specific to your application [CORE\cake\libs\debugger.php, line 688]
```

Comment: Are you trying to install Cake? This looks like it's from an install script.

Comment: yes i am trying to install cake but stuck with these kind of error

Comment: I do not think this question deserved to be closed and -3. Helped me and I am not new to cake.

Comment: The explanation for closure of this question bears little relation to the question itself or its usefulness. The view count alone is testament to this.

Answer (score 54):

You just need to do as it says:

1. Edit `yourInstallation*/app/config/core.php`
2. Search for `Security.salt` and change some random characters (this is so your application doesn't have the same security seed as a billion other installations, which would be a serious security loophole.
3. Do the same with `Security.cipherSeed` but use only numbers
4. Save `core.php`

Now read `core.php` - you'll learn a lot from doing that.

Comment: It comes out of your head, your fingers or however you want.

Comment: i have given 123456789 as Security.salt value still getting this Notice (1024): Please change the value of 'Security.salt' in app/config/core.php to a salt value specific to your application [CORE\cake\libs\debugger.php, line 684]
Notice (1024): Please change the value of 'Security.cipherSeed' in app/config/core.php to a numeric (digits only) seed value specific to your application [CORE\cake\libs\debugger.php, line 688]
Your tmp directory is writable.

The FileEngine is being used for caching. To change the config edit APP/config/core.php

Comment: Either you haven't saved the file, or you are editing the wrong one.

Comment: no   i have write Configure::write('Security.salt', '123456789'); and saved properly please help

Comment: You should change it to a value that has the same length as the original.

Comment: jesus, if it it that hard for you to change a bloody string..^^  simply alter ONE single char of it (like "a" to "b") and you're fine. although i don't see a bright cakehp future ahead of you. i mean, the instructions from the error message AND from the answers here are as clean and straight forward as they can possibly get

Comment: I Googled "SHA-1 Generator" to use for the `Security.Salt` and I found a random number generator for the `Security.cipherSeed`. I realize this post is 3 years old, but it helped me out. Thanks!

Comment: Salt and cipher seed generator for CakePHP: http://www.sethcardoza.com/tools/random-password-generator/

Comment: @Leo I have an existing cakephp application on v 2.2. I migrated to 2.9. But now its giving the same error. Its not working with the old values. If I change these values then nothing works as old data was encrypted with old Security.cipherSeed and Security.salt... Please help

Answer (score 21):

1. Go to your CakePHP app folder.
2. Enter the config folder and open `core.php`
3. You will see these lines somewhere:

   ```
   /**
    * A random string used in security hashing methods.
    */


   Configure::write('Security.salt', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
   ```

   If your CakePHP version is 1.3 or greater then this will also be there:

   ```
   /**
    * A random numeric string (digits only) used to encrypt/decrypt strings.
    */


   Configure::write('Security.cipherSeed', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
   ```

   Just change the values in:

   ```
   Configure::write('Security.cipherSeed', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
   ```

   to:

   ```
   Configure::write('Security.cipherSeed', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxTxxxxxxxx');
   ```

   or any of your choice. Just to start you can make whole value blank as well:

   ```
   Configure::write('Security.cipherSeed', '');

   Configure::write('Security.salt', '');
   ```

Then save the file, and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

See the cookbook docs - 
[11.1.4 Optional Configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/sk/compare/1532/Optional-Configuration)